# How to create a 3D LSystem?

Tags: scripting

Does anyone have any advice on how I could create a 3D LSystem in Blender? Preferably using a generative or automatic method. A 2D example below:

[image]

Comment: Do you desire such a stylized tree, or are you looking for an actual tree generator script? There is e.g. http://www.blendernation.com/2014/03/10/using-the-sapling-tree-generator/

Comment: @CoDEmanX no, I need one similar to that image, not an actual tree

Comment: @stacker I'm asking how I can make a 3D version of that binary tree in Blender.

Comment: you could make something like that with 3D easily enough.  I'll think about it and see if I can come with something.  Basically, anything that can generate a wireframe would be a good start and then use particles with a sphere to attach sphere's to all the vertex intersections.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Thank you for your answer. That is what I was after. Is there a terminology for what it is, as random tree seemed to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1)  Make a plane then enter Edit mode.

Step 2)  Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> to merge the points of the plane to a single point.

Step 3)  Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse-click to extrude points out.(Which mouse button depends on whether you have right or left click as default... I think...)

Step 4)  Add a sphere to a different layer

Step 5)  Add a particle system to the lines using the settings that I've circled in the following image.  The image also shows what an OpenGL render will look like using the default settings.

(remember to right-click any images that are difficult to see and choose -> 'View Image' to see the larger version)

[image]

Now add a skin modifier and using default settings, enter Edit mode and select all the points.  Now scale all the points using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, so far as I know this is the only tool that uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.  Normally scaling is done with <kbd>s</kbd> or by normals using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

That's pretty much it except that I did apply the Particle System in the modifier tab and since there may be overlapping spheres at some of the 'tree' vertices, you may want to join all the spheres then enter Edit mode, select everything using <kbd>a</kbd> and then use the Remove Doubles tool to clear up any overlapping vertices.

[image]